# Returning PDF from MVC controller not working on android browsers

Tags: c#, android, model-view-controller, http-headers, pdf-generation

I have a controller which is building a PDF file using pdfsharp and returning it as a file response to a GET request as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult downloadImageResultsPDF()
{    
    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Title = "myhealth.pdf";

    // Create an empty page
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    //XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

    // Create a font
    XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

    // Draw the text
    gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
      new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
      XStringFormats.Center);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Save(stream, false);
    byte[] myFile = stream.ToArray();

    Response.ClearHeaders();

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename='myhealth.pdf'");

    return File(myFile, "application/pdf");
}
```

I am calling this controller from my razor using:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("downloadImageResultsPDF","Home")">Download</a>
```

Everything seems to work fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE11 on desktop, Chrome and Safari on iOS and Firefox on Android 6.0

I cannot get it to work on Chrome on Android or Android's default browser. The download seems to start but then I get "Download Unsuccessful." The file is shown as 'Untitled' in the downloads folder.

I have also tried using octet-stream as file type, and using a .PDF extension (rather than .pdf). I've tried adding/removing quotes to the filename but still nothing. I've also tried using attachment and inline in the content-disposition header.

I also tried serving a static pdf file.

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='myhealth.pdf'");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to get the download working on Android with Chrome or the default browser based on the version of Android. You need to make a `HttpPost`.
In my instance I had a list of files that could be downloaded. So I capture the id of the file in a hiddenvariable and pass it to the Action as a route value.

View

```
input type="hidden" name="docid" id="docid" value=""

input id="btnSubmit" data-id="${DownloadsId}" type="submit" value="Download" onclick="handleCopy(this)"

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleCopy(e) {
        var $el = $(e);
        var dataId = $el.attr("data-id");
        document.getElementById("docid").value = dataId;
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("List/{id}")]
[ActionName("List")]
public FileResult RequestFile(int? docid)
{
    if (docid == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    Downloads downloads = db.Downloads.Find(docid);

    if (downloads == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (downloads.FileData != null)
    {
        string fileName = downloads.Filename;
        return File(downloads.FileData.Data, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, fileName);
    }
}
```